# User Last Login Sort Column

Tags: users, user-meta, columns

I've seen there are several ways to display a user's last login date on the Users page without having to use a 3rd party plugin. Building on that, I'd really like to have the user's last login date column be sortable (hopefully orderby date).

I'm using the display user last login function via [wpdailybits](http://wpdailybits.com/blog/capture-user-last-login-time/705), but my additions to the code can't get the column to sort.

Suggestions? I know I'm missing something...

```
//Capture User Last Login
    add_action('wp_login','wpdb_capture_user_last_login', 10, 2);
    function wpdb_capture_user_last_login($user_login, $user){
        update_user_meta($user->ID, 'last_login', current_time('mysql'));
    }

//Display Last Login Date in Admin
    add_filter( 'manage_users_columns', 'wpdb_user_last_login_column');
    function wpdb_user_last_login_column($columns){
        $columns['lastlogin'] = __('Last Login', 'lastlogin');
        return $columns;
    }

    add_action( 'manage_users_custom_column',  'wpdb_add_user_last_login_column', 10, 3); 
    function wpdb_add_user_last_login_column($value, $column_name, $user_id ) {
        if ( 'lastlogin' != $column_name )
            return $value;

        return get_user_last_login($user_id,false);
    }

    function get_user_last_login($user_id,$echo = true){
        $date_format = get_option('date_format') . ' ' . get_option('time_format');
        $last_login = get_user_meta($user_id, 'last_login', true);
        $login_time = 'Never logged in';
        if(!empty($last_login)){
           if(is_array($last_login)){
                $login_time = mysql2date($date_format, array_pop($last_login), false);
            }
            else{
                $login_time = mysql2date($date_format, $last_login, false);
            }
        }
        if($echo){
            echo $login_time;
        }
        else{
            return $login_time;
        }
    }
//Sort the Columns
    add_filter( 'manage_edit-users_sortable_columns', 'sortable_users_column' );
    function sortable_users_column( $sortable_columns  ) {

        $sortable_columns[ 'last_login_column' ] = 'lastlogin';

    }
```

Comment: The `'manage_edit-users_sortable_columns'` filter handle is not proper. I use `'manage_users_sortable_columns'` instead, which works! I got this tip from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/267787/142701).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anywhere in your code that the query is being modified. Just flagging a column to be sortable doesn't mean it knows how to sort the data - it will just add the little up/down arrow and make the column clickable but you have to intercept the query var accordingly and tell WP what to do. You'll want to hook into `pre_get_users` and modify the query accordingly. Since you're already storing the time using `current_time( 'mysql' )` then the default ordering should work as intended.

This is untested but should work or at least get you started.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_users', 'wpse_filter_user_query' );
function wpse_filter_user_query( $user_query ) {
    global $current_screen;

    if ( !is_admin() || 'users' != $current_screen->id ) 
        return;

    if( 'lastlogin' == $user_query->get( 'orderby' ) ) 
    {
        $user_query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' ); 
        $user_query->set( 'meta_key', 'last_login' );
    } 
}
```

Comment: If this really is an _action_, then it will not use any `return` value. It probably is a filter or you have to reference it: `&$user_query` to have any affect on the actual query.

Comment: @kaiser spot on. After looking up the `pre_user_query` hook again, it occurred to me that hooking into `pre_get_users` is probably a better fit, although they will both work. Updated the answer based on your feedback and the updated hook.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `'manage_users_sortable_columns'` filter handle instead.

```
//Sort the Columns
    add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', 'sortable_users_column' );

    function sortable_users_column( $sortable_columns  ) {
        $sortable_columns[ 'last_login_column' ] = 'lastlogin';
    }
```

That's the proper one for the users admin screen.